# How to integrate this function without using the transformation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I want to integrate the function $\int_\mathbb{R^n} \psi_{\epsilon}(|x|_2) dx$ where we have $\psi_{\epsilon} ( t) = 1$ for $0\le t \le R$
$\psi_{\epsilon} ( t) = 1+\frac{R - t}{\epsilon}$ for $0\le t \le R$
and $0$ elsewhere.
My problem is, that we have not developed integration theory so far, that I could use the transformation for multiple variables and switch to spherical coordinates, because this map is NOT a diffeomorphism and we proved the transformation theorem only for diffeomorphism. Probably, there is a work-around available for this situation, so that I could still use spherical coordinates?

If not, I will probably have to do this in cartesian ones, but I do not see how to handle this.
The integral we defined so far is the iterative riemann integral for continuous functions on compact support.

My problem is that I do not see how to do this without inventing a lot of theory.
An idea I had is to derive the right equation illegaly by using the transformation theorem without proving it and then verify the equation by induction, but I do not see how to derive the equation for the integral over the n-sphere from the one over the n-1 sphere. This is at least an idea, since there are several recursive ways available to determine the volume of the n-sphere.

Comment: Consider the integral over $B_R(0)$ and over $B_R(0)^c$. Things should be fine in the appropriate regions.

Comment: and how shall I integrate this thing on $B_R(0)$ in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Do you have a theorem for change of variables in spherical coordinates for a region like that? The alternative is to approximate your function with a smooth function and then take the limit.

Comment: Yes, for a region like that, but not for spherical coordinates, as the map from cartesians to spherical ones it not a diffeomorphism. Do you have any sequence of functions in mind?